# How to extract an "enum" from an OpenAPI 3.0.0 schema into its own class instead of creating it inside another class when generating code

Tags: openapi, openapi-generator, openapi-generator-maven-plugin

I'm using the `open-api-generator-maven-plugin` with the `spring` generator to generate code from an OpenAPI 3.0.0 yaml schema file.
Inside the file there are several defined properties with an enum

```
      properties:
        requestTypeKey:
          type: string
          description: purchase
          enum:
            - purchase
```

This generates code as follows

```
public class PurchaseRequest {
   public enum RequestTypeKeyEnum {
       PURCHASE("purchase");
   }
}

public class SomeOtherPurchaseRequest {
   public enum RequestTypeKeyEnum {
       PURCHASE("purchase");
   }
}
```

The problem is that this inner class enum is generated for multiple different classes.
Now whenever I have to compare the enums I have to prefix the enum with the encompassing class every time and can't directly compare the enums, but have to get their value as a string and compare those with each others.

What I'm looking for is some sort of option or plugin that scans the schema for enums that have identical values and extracts them to their own class which can be reused.

So it would look like this

```
public enum RequestTypeKeyEnum {
   PURCHASE("purchase");
}

public class PurchaseRequest {
   public RequestTypeKeyEnum requestTypeEnum;
}

public class SomeOtherPurchaseRequest {
   public RequestTypeKeyEnum requestTypeEnum;
}
```

I know that this problem can be solved by using `$ref` inside the schema file, but the schema file is provided to me from an external source, so if it's ever updated I'll have to rewrite it again which is something I'd like to avoid.

I looked through the documentation for the [generator](https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/generators/spring) and the [general configuration options](https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/configuration), but couldn't find a suitable solutions to my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Please check this example to achieve this:

```
paths:
  /products:
    get:
      parameters:
      - in: query
        name: color
        required: true
        schema:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/Color'
      responses:
        '200':
          description: OK
components:
  schemas:
    Color:
      type: string
      enum:
        - black
        - white
        - red
        - green
        - blue
```

Taken from here https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/enums/

Comment: OP said he cannot alter the schema, so this is not answering it